# Composition of Continuous functions in Metric Space (Proof Verification)

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

I want to show that the composition of two continuous function is a continuous function.

So let there be $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z $  two continuous functions($(X,d)$, $(Y, \rho )$, and $(Z,\iota )$ are metric spaces). We will prove that $gof:X\rightarrow Z$ is a continuous function.

Let there be $x_0 \in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ .So  $f(x_0) \in Y$. g is continuous therefore there exists $\lambda>0$ such that for all $x\in X$ we get $\rho (f(x_0),f(x))< \lambda  \Rightarrow \iota (g(f(x_0),g(f(x)))<\epsilon $

f is continuous as well therefore  there exists $ \delta >0$  such that for all $x \in X$ we get $ d(x_0,x) <\delta \Rightarrow \rho (f(x_0),f(x))<\lambda $ . Therefore $gof:X \rightarrow Z$ is continuous because given $x_0 \in X$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta $ such that for all $x\in X$, $d(x_0,x)<\delta \Rightarrow \iota (gof(x_0),gof(x)))< \epsilon $ as desired.

Can someone verify this proof? The lecturer proved it with an equivalent definition for continuity and I preferred to prove it with the definition that I am used to. Thanks!

Comment: It seems fine to me. But there are little typing mistakes, i think. In third paragraph, $\rho (f(x_0),f(x))< \lambda  \Rightarrow \iota (g(f(x_0),g(f(x))) $ should be corrected that $\rho (f(x_0),f(x))< \lambda  \Rightarrow \iota (g(f(x_0),g(f(x)))<\epsilon $. Similarly in fifth paragraph, $d(x_0,x)<\delta \Rightarrow \iota (gof(x_0),gof(x))) $ should be corrected that $d(x_0,x)<\delta \Rightarrow \iota (gof(x_0),gof(x)))<\epsilon $.

Comment: @Tgymasb  you are correct, thanks for correcting me and for the feedback